# PyTelegramBotApi. AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'TeleBot'

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Из библиотек с ботами установлена только **PyTelegramBotApi** и с другими библиотеками не конфликтуют. Аргумент **telebot.TeleBot()** написан правильно.Через VPN запускать пробовал, аналогичная ошибка. При запуске скрипта с расширением ****.py**(имя скрипта не **telebot**) ругает первую строчку кода  **AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'TeleBot'**. Все, что нашел в Google, все попробовал, в теле вопроса все расписал. Какие могут быть еще варианты решения. Спасибо за уделённое время.

```
import telebot

MypyBot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN заменён на свой, получен от BotFather в Telegram', parse_mode = None)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как установлена библиотека? и спасибо за токен на скриншоте

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых - проверьте, установлена ли у вас библиотека, и установлена ли она у вас правильно. Для верности можно полностью ее удалить

```
pip uninstall pytelegrambotapi
pip install --no-cache-dir pytelegrambotapi
```

Проблема, вероятно, именно в самом установленном модуле, ибо даже ваш код у меня запускается абсолютно нормально.
Как пример, небольшой эхо-бот:

```
import telebot

MypyBot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN', parse_mode = None)

@MypyBot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def replyer(message):
    MypyBot.reply_to(message, message.text)

MypyBot.polling()
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю это потому что вместе с вашим файлом существует файл **telebot.py**. Если так то удалите этот файл. Потом снова запустите свою программу. ***Проблема решена***.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install --user pytelegrambotapi
```

**в PyCharm:**

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
2. Выбираете ваш проект
3. и на + добавляете `pytelegrambotapi`
4. снизу кнопочка install